# Fiddler not capturing requests from C# application

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, fiddler

I was trying to run Fiddler (v4.6.0.2, built August 17, 2015) to capture outgoing requests from a C# WebAPI application (.NET 4.5.2) to Amazon web services.

I have set the proxy configuration in web.config (the application is running under my domain user account) as per the [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/V3/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-config-ref.html) as well as the [Telerik documentation](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler):

```
<aws region="us-west-2" profileName="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
  <proxy host="127.0.0.1" port="8888"/>
</aws>

<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="False" bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

When Fiddler runs, it dutifully captures all traffic coming from my browser. I know that my application is routing its web requests properly because if I turn Fiddler off, I get exceptions due to being unable to connect to the proxy. However, the problem is none of the application's requests to Amazon are showing up in Fiddler. I turned off all filters in Fiddler to make sure I hadn't accidentally hidden those requests.

I also tried it in a Windows console application connecting to internal web services and I had the same behavior. Am I missing any other settings? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I typically do *not* proxy through fiddler for my web apps.

I *do* however ensure that my app pool for the site is running as my domain user account, and then I am able to inspect traffic between my (local) web server, and external services.

I also use full IIS, not Casini or other in-built web server.

Finally, I also have an entry in my hosts file (local.mydomain.com) pointing to 127.0.0.1 and connect to my test site via that url

Answer (score -1):

If the proxy settings cause your app to work only while Fiddler is running and fail when it's not, you have a Filter set in Fiddler that's hiding the traffic. Click the `Help` > `Troubleshoot` menu in Fiddler and try again.

If not:

I don't think I understand what the `aws` XML section in your screenshot is meant to represent?

Is there some reason you've capitalized `False` in your xml?

Did you edit the appropriate `config` file for the bitness of your application? Are you editing app.exe.config or machine.config?